# How to work with 'NEX 530 NFC RFID' reader in C#?

Tags: c#, nfc, rfid

I have to use 'NEX 530 NFC RFID' reader in a C# windows application.

The Nex-530 desktop reader is a Mifare ISO14443A, B or ISO15693 read/write device with a typical operating distance of 50‐100mm.

The SDK and sample codes are in C language and I didn't find anything about this device on the internet.

How can I connect to this device on a .NET platform?

Comment: Please, do not spam with tags

Answer (score 1):

It seems to communicate through serial communication.
I suggest you to try to read value this way :

```
using (var sp = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM1", 115200, System.IO.Ports.Parity.None, 8, System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One))
{
    sp.Open();

    var readData = sp.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(readData);
}
```

You can find the serial port in Windows at `Computer Management -> Device Manager` for example :

[image: Device Manager Serial Device]

To test serial communication, you can use [Putty](https://www.putty.org/) to check if you can read value from the device and to fine-tune serial communication parameters. If it's working with Putty, the code above should work.